# Redirect to subdomain and changing different paths

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've changed my blog to a sub-domain.

i.e. www.domain.com/blog -> blog.domain.com

Simple rule fixes this and all paths:

```
1 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^blog\.camcloud\.com$ [NC]
2 RewriteRule ^blog$ https://blog.camcloud.com [L,R=301]
3 RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ https://blog.camcloud.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This moves all corresponding paths after this appropriately. Although the first question is do I combine line #2 and #3 into 1 rule? I found that just typing www.domain.com/blog doesn't redirect to blog.domain.com otherwise.

The other question I have is that I've explicitly redirected other paths this way:

```
Redirect 301 /blog/tags/tag/foo https://blog.domain.com/tag/foo
```

essentially I'm removing "tags" and keeping the rest of the path (while changing the domain of course). But this doesn't work as it leaves "tags" in there:

> https://blog.domain.com/tags/tag/foo

I guess because of the previous rules? The same thing happens with another path:

```
Redirect 301 /blog/categories/industry https://blog.domain.com/category/news/industry-news
```

There are only a few of these and have completely different paths so I thought a simple Redirect would work but it still keeps "categories" in the url. So it gets redirected like so:

> https://blog.domain.com/categories/industry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing rules from two different modules `mod_rewrite` (`RewriteRule`) and `mod_alias` (`Redirect`). Better to keep all the rules using `mod_alias` as this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# specific redirects first
RewriteRule ^blog/categories/industry/?$ https://blog.domain.com/category/news/industry-news [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^blog/tags/(tag/foo/?)$ https://blog.domain.com/$1 [L,NC,R=301]

# now catch-all rule to redirect everything from /blog to new sub-domain
RewriteRule ^blog(/.*)?$ https://blog.camcloud.com$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

- This is assuming `/blog/` directory has no .htaccess
- Make sure to clear your browser cache before you test this